# How to share BroadcastChannel between scopes?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a `BroadcastChannel` as a buffer. I send values at one scope and would like to observe them using flow at another.

My code is:

```
val channel = BroadcastChannel<Int>(1)

val observable = channel.asFlow()

someScope.launch {
   channel.send(42)
}

otherScope.launch {
  observable.collect {
    print(it)
  }
}
```

Some information:

1. otherScope lives longer then someScope
2. When collect at the same scope I received values

Comment: You should probably use `SharedFlow` instead. It's going to replace `BroadcastChannel` in the future: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/

Comment: Anyway, what exactly is the problem with your code? What did you expect, and what actually happens?

Comment: @marstran I expect to receive value from channel in another scope

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with `collect` operator that block other collections.
Have replaced with `onEach` and `launchIn` and everything works as expected